# Assign List property on Select LINQ statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

So i want to achieve something like:

```
 var query = from p in db.Project
                        select new A
                        {
                            Project = p,
                            Capacity = new List<Capacity>((from pp in db.ProjectActualCapacity                                                              
                                                           where pp.ProjectID == p.ID
                                                           select new Capacity
                                                           {
                                                               Actual = pp.Hours,                                                                 
                                                               Date = pp.Date,
                                                               ProjectID = pp.ProjectID
                                                           }
                                                            ).ToList())
                        };
```

However, when the query is converted to list. It throws the following error

> Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Is there a workaround to this?

thanks

//Update

```
public class Capacity
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal? Actual { get; set; }
    public decimal? Projected { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How you declare `Capacity` class?

Comment: You just can't use List<T> constructor with IEnumerable<T> as parameter.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti [Ummm, yes you can.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: List<T>(IEnumerable<T>) is a constructor

Comment: @Adam What I think he means is that you cannot use that constructor overload with Linq to entities.

Comment: @Maarten I love it when people mean one thing but the language they use conveys something else :-)

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth you can but you can't do it in LINQ to Entities (that's why he gets that error message). .ToList() is enough (as Maarteen posted).

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth it's just a short comment to read **in the context of his question** ;)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Yeah fair enough ;-) I'm just googling his error message and finding lots of duplicates around, but none of the answers are particularly informative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are explicitly creating a list and using the constructor which accepts an enumerable. This is not necessary since you are already using `.ToList()` where you define that collection.

Also, your Capacity class needs a parameterless constructor.

So I think it will work like this.

```
var query = from p in db.Project
    select new A {
        Project = p,
        Capacity = (from pp in db.ProjectActualCapacity                                                              
                    where pp.ProjectID == p.ID
                    select new Capacity {
                        Actual = pp.Hours,                                                                 
                        Date = pp.Date,
                        ProjectID = pp.ProjectID
                    }
                   ).ToList())
   };
```